# Delete rows out of many where everything is same except one

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to delete row number 1 and 3, which when compared with row number 2, are same except for procurement_type. There are many more cases like this. This is just for an illustration. Please suggest me sql queries for oracle sql.

[image]

Comment: why 1 and 3, but not 3 and 2?

Comment: Exactly; why would you want to keep #2? What's the rule behind your statement? Because, the simplest option is then (very simplified) `delete from that_table where procurement_type = 'E'`

Comment: Because there are some rows where i don't want to delete procurement _type = 'E'. I only want to delete procurement _type = 'E' if there is similar material text with procurement _type = 'F'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your later comment:

```
DELETE 
  FROM some_table st
 WHERE procurement _type = 'E'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM some_table st
                WHERE procurement _type = 'F'
                  AND srn = st.srn
                      ... /* the other columns you want to compare with*/);
```